# Use hash select for an array

Tags: ruby

I have a hash

```
h = {a=> 1, b=> 2, c=> 3}
```

and an array

```
a = [a, b]
```

Is it possible to use

```
h.select {|k,v| k == array_here?}
```

To select all elements from the array that exists in the hash?

**I Found the Solution**

```
h.select {|k,v| a.include?(k) }
```

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it

Comment: You are asking for _"all elements from the array that exist in the hash"_, but instead wanting _"all elements from the hash whose keys exist in the array"_. The question was misleading and resulted with wrong answers.

Comment: I think is the same. all elements from the array that exist in the hash has the same meaning as all elements from the hash whose keys exist in the array!

Comment: It is not. In your solution you will get an array of [k, v] in R1.8, a hash in R1.9. This is definitely not the same as elements of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible and the easiest answer is:

```
h.select {|k,v| a.include?(k) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going about it backwards. Try this:

```
a.select {|e| h.has_key? e }
```

Comment: This is not working. The correct is `h.select {|k,v| a.include?(k) }`

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that with something like:

```
a.each do |arr_elem| 
  new_hash[arr_elem] = h[arr_elem] unless h[arr_elem].nil?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want what you have asked (i. e. elements of an array which present as keys in a hash):

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
a = [:a, :b, :d]
a & h.keys
```